# Trying to render an image, but #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []> is returned

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

my guides can have many guide_pics. In my show guide view, I want to show the pics. I'm trying to use

```
<%= image_tag @guide.guide_pics if @guide.guide_pics %>
```

Instead of the image, the page renders with the text:

So it seems like something is there, I just have to get the picture.

But in the debugger this gives

```
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

Does that mean an empty object is returned? If that is the case, maybe I seeded the db wrong:

```
g1.guide_pics.build(picture: File.open(File.join(Rails.root, '/public/2015-08-28 18.55.47.jpg')))
```

Otherwise, maybe I set up the association wrong.

My guide_pic model

```
class GuidePic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :guide
  validates :guide_id, presence: true
  validates :picture, presence: true

  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
end
```

My guide model

```
class Guide < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :guide_pics, dependent: :destroy

  #mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
end
```

Comment: It is not logic to render *ONE* image if a Guide *HAS MANY* guide_pics

Comment: Correct. I didn't make clear that I was first trying to get an image to render. Once I figured that out, I would render all the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails is doing correctly, you are misunderstanding.

while a model is having many pictures (has_many relation) rails is auto-generating a method to access those.

In this case Guide.guide_pics is making a query to the DB, something like
`SELECT * from guide_pics where guide_id=5`
as you can see - this is selecting all rows, the hole set of data which is associated with one guide. This is what ActiveRecord is called an ActiveRecord::Collection.

First of all, **yes, you seeded the DB wrong!**. The `.build` method is not saving anything to the database, you should call the `.create` method.

If you are having any objects in your database you have 2 (3) ways of rendering the image.

`<%= image_tag @guide.guide_pics.first.url if @guide.guide_pics.any? %>`

This will take the first picture from the Collection if any is in there.
This is **bad code**. 
another option would be to say `.take` instead of .first.

better code would be something like

`<%= image_tag @guide.preview_picture %>`

to do so you need a model function

```
class Guide
  def preview_picture
    guide_pics.first.url || "/images/no-logo.jpg"
  end
end
```

this will automatically takes the first picture or returns the string of a default one.

my advise to you: have a look on Carrierwave, Dragonfyl or Paperclip. Thise are awesome FileUploading Gems - fitting your needs.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up my misunderstandings. I seeded the database with create, like you suggested. I'll iterate properly later, for now using @guide.guide_pics.first.picture, I get "<File:0x00000007035528>". That string is what is rendered. So now the question is how do I get it to render the picure?

Answer (score 3):

`guide_pics` is an association, and will return one or more `guide_pics`.

So you will have to iterate over all `guide_pics`, as follows:

```
<% @guide.guide_pics.each do |guide_pic| %>
  <%= image_tag guide_pic.picture.url %>
<% end %>
```

Notice I write `guide_pic.picture.url`: I am assuming you are using a gem for your attachments, like carrierwave or something similar, which can build a url for your image --if not, you will do add that yourself.

But if you just want to show the first picture, you could do something like

```
<%= image_tag @guide.guide_pics.first.picture.url if @guide.guide_pics.count > 0 %>
```

Comment: I think CarrierWave is what I have to figure out next. I am seeding with g1.guide_pics.create!(picture: File.open(File.join(Rails.root, '/public/2015-08-28 18.55.47.jpg'))). There is no url method on my picture.

Comment: Well, carrierwave was trivial. I just had to mount it to my guide_pic model with mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation of [image_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag) it expects source of image not `collection_proxy` You need to iterate the list and show images one by one

```
<% @guide.guide_pics.each do |pic|%>
  <%= image_tag pic %>
<% end %>
```

Note: pic can be url or name of pic depending on your pics saving technique.